# Microsoft Teams : Not receiving messages on messaging endpoint having ngrok

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft teams is not making a call back to our ngrok URL hosted on our local machines. When we change the ngrok URL to a publicly accessible google cloud URL everything works fine. Is there any problem with calling ngrok URLs from MS Teams?

Comment: Is your bot receiving messages? Are you following steps mentioned to [configure Messaging extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#messaging-extensions)? Could you please share your app manifest as well?

Comment: Well, the bot was receiving messages until yesterday, with a different ngrok url. We aren't using Messaging extensions. We just use a bot and the set the bot endpoint address to the ngrok based endpoint: https://31d3dcfd.ngrok.io/api/spock_msteams_webhook

Comment: I'm able to curl to this ngrok url but I can't get the Teams App to send out messages to it today. Was fine until yesterday.

Comment: Also please let me know how I can share my manifest if that may be of use?

Comment: I did no code changes, but the same setup is working today!!! Wonder why the messages weren't coming through yesterday?

Comment: There was an issue due to which messages were sent to older messaging endpoint. This has been fixed.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I am having issues with installation messages, can you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415130/generating-a-conversationupdate-type-message-while-installing-an-app

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue due to which messages were sent to older messaging endpoint. This has been fixed.

*Note:Adding answer from comments.*